# Wimi Defence Review

Tags: privacy, mobile, anonymity

Did anybody use [Wimi Defence](http://www.fortresscryptophone.com/)? If yes, then how was your experience after using it and also review its security? I didn't find any of it that's why am asking here.

Comment: I've never heard of it, which automatically raises concerns that it hasn't been widely audited. Comparatively, the [Silent Circle](https://www.silentcircle.com/products-and-solutions/devices/) mobile devices are generally trusted as a reasonable option for secure communications, particularly if you use [Signal](https://whispersystems.org/) (previously TextSecure and RedPhone, before they unified it into one app) for messaging and calls.

Comment: Sir Silent Circle had critical bug bounty which allow hacker to control the device's modem and call functions..... here you can check.   http://www.zdnet.com/article/severe-silent-circle-blackphone-vulnerability-lets-hackers-take-over/

Comment: Yup, it was introduced through an nVidia binary blob deployed on the device, and fixed within 1 day. Every piece of software on the planet has bugs, some of which will be security issues. The only difference between secure software and regular software is the approach taken in development, patching, and defense in depth approaches (e.g. applying and configuring PaX / SELinux).

Answer (score 3):

This looks very suspicious for me:

- It claims to be a winner of "ultra secure phone 2015" without any references and without that anything like this can be found on the internet.
- It does not provide any technical details.
- It claims to use have totally unbreakable encryption with **random** keysize which is just cryptographic rubbish.

Comment: Hmmm... That's some of the problem am suffering with it too.

Answer (score -1):

It steals your information. Don't download it, don't install it and don't use it.

They claim to protect your privacy but in reality they steal it and sell it…

Comment: No links/sources to prove the claim. Also the question is opinion based. PS: I have never used this product.